# Why is program behaving this way?

Tags: java

Following is my code which adds products of all 3 digit numbers into an array List. Then prints those numbers which are palindrome. I am getting 121 as output. Why not other palindrome number??

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class eular {
    int reverse=0;


    public boolean palindrome( Integer num){
        int remainder=0;
        int n=num;
        while(num!=0){
            remainder = num % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            num = num / 10;
                    }
        if(n==reverse)
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        eular e=new eular();
        ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=100;i<=999;i++)
        for(int j=100;j<=999;j++){

        a.add(i*j);

        }
        for (Integer integer : a) {

    if(e.palindrome(integer)){
        System.out.println(integer);;
    }

        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Because in your arraylist only 121 is a palindrome and hence the value is printed...

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to see what is happend? I am not the downvoter

Comment: But there are others too like 9009,etc Where are other numbers?

Comment: How come you get 121 as output when it can't be in the list at all? Your program does not return any output when I run it.

Comment: Also your code requires some modification

Comment: @  RealSkeptic : I was getting 121 for I,j=10 to 99.In this 2 digit case also I am not getting 9009?

Answer (score 7):

Your `reverse` variable should be initialized every time you call a `palindrome` method. Move the line `int reverse=0;` inside that method.

Answer (score 3):

First, you've *forgot to declare* `reverse` (edit: or did it in the wrong context as a field of `euler` class: in that case you have to assign `reverse` to zero before each call of the `palindrome`):

```
   // static: you don't want "this"
   public static boolean palindrome(Integer num) { 
     int n = num; 
     int reverse = 0; // <- this was omitted (or misplaced as a field of euler)

     while (num != 0) {
       reverse = reverse * 10 + num % 10;
       num = num / 10;
     } 

     // ifs can be so ugly...
     return n == reverse;
   }
```

Second, you don't want that *huge arrays*:

```
   ...
   for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
     for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
       int item = i * j;

       if (palindrome(item))
         System.out.println(item);
     }
```

Comment: No, he didn't forget, he just declared it as a variable of euler and not a local variable in the method. And list of 810000 Integers shouldn't be critical. Of course, not required, but also not really critical.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz: in this case it's a plausible cause of the error: `reverse` should be `assigned to zero` before each call of `palindrome`

Comment: Yes, it should, but that does not mean "just" adding reverse, but moving it (from the class into the method). This was not "omitted", but "misplaced".